# sed error when launching terminal on OS X

Tags: macos, bash, terminal, zsh, sed

I get these error messages when launching bash or zsh in standard Terminal.app or iTerm2

```
sed: 1: "\#^system_type=# { s#^s ...": extra characters at the end of p command
sed: 1: "\#^system_type=# { s#^s ...": extra characters at the end of p command
sed: 1: "\#^system_name=# { s#^s ...": extra characters at the end of p command
sed: 1: "\#^system_name=# { s#^s ...": extra characters at the end of p command
sed: 1: "\#^system_name_lowercas ...": extra characters at the end of p command
sed: 1: "\#^system_name_lowercas ...": extra characters at the end of p command
sed: 1: "\#^system_version=# { s ...": extra characters at the end of p command
sed: 1: "\#^system_version=# { s ...": extra characters at the end of p command
sed: 1: "\#^system_arch=# { s#^s ...": extra characters at the end of p command
sed: 1: "\#^system_arch=# { s#^s ...": extra characters at the end of p command
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: Is this bash or zsh? Why have you tagged with both?

Comment: Errors appear both in bash and zsh.

Comment: Ah! Then the problem is most likely in `/etc/profile`. Have you changed that file? Did you try the `grep` command from my answer?

Comment: There is nothing remotely suspicious in `/etc/profile` and `~/.profile` and I haven't changed these files recently. `grep` doesn't give any results either.

Answer (score 1):

Check the `.bash_profile` file in your home directory. The commands in this file are read whenever a terminal starts.

The offending `sed` commands should be found in that file, if not then check `/etc/profile for`sed` commands.

Answer (score 0):

This means that you have some incorrect `sed` commands in one of your shell's initalization files. Since you're using bash and OSX, this will be one of `~/.profile`,`~/.bash_profile`,`/etc/profile`, `/etc/environment` (though the latter is extremely unlikely). To find out which one, run

```
grep system_type ~/.profile ~/.bash_profile /etc/profile /etc/environment
```

You've also tagged this as `zsh`. I know that OSX runs bash login shells by default, but I have no idea if they've done the same for `zsh`. Assuming they haven't and `zsh` starts a normal non-login shell, you should check `~/.zsshrc` at least. Not sure what other startup files `zsh` sources.